# Create-react-app returns "Cannot find module 'rxjs'"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I've just installed NodeJS and NPM in a new machine. I added `rxjs` package in all my existing projects in order to make then start properly. However, when I run `create-react-app` - using npm globally or npx - I receive "Error: Cannot find module 'rxjs'
". Seems like `rxjs` is a new dependency of something (considering it's affecting old projects too).

I have already changed Node version to 8, 10 and 12. Reinstalled NPM, changed CRA version to 2.x.x and the trouble persists.

How can I use CRA without this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by the Original Poster in the comments, the fix could be to clear your cache.

`npm cache clean --force`

If this still doesn't work, you can follow the steps below to install and try with Yarn:

If neither `npx create-react-app my-app` and `npm init react-app my-app` are working for you, try Yarn to see how it goes.

I have used CRA is multiple projects on Windows, Ubuntu, Mint and macOS and have never explicitly installed rxjs, nor have I been asked for it. This leads me to think that this problem is almost certainly caused by sth local to *you* rather than sth wrong with CRA. I assume that you have searched through their issues on Github.

**Try it with Yarn**
Open a new terminal (linux and macOS) or command line (Windows) session cd'd to your documents folder or suitable alternative. Then run:

macOS

`brew install yarn`

`yarn create react-app my-app`

Windows (with Chocolatey)

`choco install yarn`

`yarn create react-app my-app`

Ubuntu

`curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -`

`echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list`

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn`

`yarn create react-app my-app`

Comment: Same with yarn. Yep, I have searched and there is no issue about it on GitHub.

Comment: What OS are you using?
You mentioned that it was a new computer, so I assume that it was a clean install, correct?
What do you get when you run:

`node --version && npm --version && create-react-app --version`

Comment: I'm using Fedora 29. I made a clean install of it on SSD. I was using Fedora 28 on HDD with no problem.

NodeJS: v10.15.3
NPM: 6.4.1
CRA: 3.0.0

Comment: If I have understood correctly, I think that the best course of action is would be to open a ticket with CRA with a minimal example for replication.

Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: Np. Thank you anyway. It doesn't seem to be a CRA problem since `rxjs` was required to other projects created months ago.

Comment: `npm cache clean --force` and reinstalling CRA, version 3.0.1 now, solved my problem. I believe the first step was the real solution.